# Is there a way to connect MySQL to a SQL DB using PHP and not using mssql_pconnect()?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to connect a MySQL server (a gs server from mediaTemple) to a MySQL server using PHP, I cannot use the mssql_pconnect() function because they don't support it for their gs servers so I'm looking for an alternate route, I don't know if it's even possible.

What I want is to generate a connection on the MySQL server using PHP that will allow me to retrieve certain information from a View on a different server that's running SQL.

Comment: What do you mean by connecting MySQL to an SQL database? What programming language?

Comment: you want to connect a MSSQL server to a MySQL server using php?  Please elaborate, and why not use mssql_pconnect? (which is for MSSQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably don't support mssql_pconnect() because its for connecting to MSSQL and not MySQL, try using mysql_connect() or mysql_pconnect();

You should be able to establish 2 different database connections to 2 mysql servers simultaneously, as long as the host doesn't have some firewall rule that blocks the connection or some other safeguard like selinux.

Comment: I am getting "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initialcommunication packet'" could it be a firewall?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on the hosters end ?  Is the server (thats not at mediatemple) accessable via port 3306 on the internet ?  Maybe you need to open the firewall on the remote host...

Comment: it's accessable via port 1433 I don't know if 3306 is open

Comment: port 1433 is MSSQL, so you don't want 2 mysql servers, you want 1 mysql, 1 mssql.

Comment: ok, so I'll ask them to open port 3306 so I can connect via mysql and make those connections work, should I worry about anything else I may not be forseeing here? (This is my first MySQL to SQL connection)

Comment: 3306 is mysql's default port, so unless you know the default has been changed, you need port 3306 to connect remotely.  You will also need to make sure the user has sufficient permissions via the 'grant' tool which populates the `mysql`.`users` table.  Users are granted permission via user@host or user@% (wildcard) so the user you connect via will need perms.  But other then that you should be able to connect to a remote mysql database.